# Update Pivot Data Range String or Range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a code that I've pieced together, but what I'm finding is that after the "used" range is found (I'm trying not to use `.usedrange` due to reliability) is that the `SourceData:=` is expecting a string (I think).

Is there a way to pass through the range from the `Data` sheet to the pivot table data range? I tried appending `RealUsedRange.Address`, but that was no luck either.

```
Sub UpdatePivotRange()

    Dim Rng1        As Range
    Dim oWB         As Workbook
    Dim oWS         As Worksheet
    Dim DataSheet   As Worksheet
    Dim oPT         As PivotTable

    Set oWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set DataSheet = oWB.Sheets("Data")
    Set Rng1 = RealUsedRange

    If Rng1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no used range, the worksheet is empty."
    Else
        For Each oWS In oWB.Worksheets
            For Each oPT In oWS.PivotTables
            'ERRROR BEGINS HERE #####
                oPT.ChangePivotCache _
                    oWB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Rng1)
            'ERROR ENDS HERE #####
            Next oPT
        Next oWS
    End If

End Sub

Public Function RealUsedRange() As Range

    Dim FirstRow        As Long
    Dim LastRow         As Long
    Dim FirstColumn     As Integer
    Dim LastColumn      As Integer
    Dim DataSheet       As Worksheet
    Dim oWB             As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set DataSheet = oWB.Sheets("Data")
        With DataSheet

             FirstRow = DataSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
             xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row

             FirstColumn = DataSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
             xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column

             LastRow = DataSheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

             LastColumn = DataSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

             Set RealUsedRange = Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

         End With
    MsgBox "The range is" & RealUsedRange.Address
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to amend the errored line by adding:

```
oPT.ChangePivotCache _
                    oWB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Data!" & Rng1.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1))
```

Hope this helps anyone looking in the future.